# Activate a breakpoint when an error occurs and when running a PHPUnit test in debugmode

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

In the past I have created serveral `C#` unit tests, in which I could activate a breakpoint when an specific error occured and when I was running in debugmode. This code was something like this:

```
if(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
  System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

But now I want to do the same thing in `PHPUnit` (with `Selenium Webdriver`). Does anyone knows how to do this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you are using Xdebug, then you can emit a breakpoint in the code with

```
xdebug_break();
```

See: http://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions

I'd not recommend to leave this in production code but if you do, check if the xdebug extension is loaded like this:

```
if (extension_loaded('xdebug')) {
    xdebug_break();
}
```